# VSTO C# Cache data for excel

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I want to know if this is possible with vsto.

Can I create an addin that can cache many records, e.g. more than the excel row count, lets say 2 million (read from a database)... and have a pivot table run off from the data cache?

Any views appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: VSTO does not extend Excel in this manner.

Comment: Can it be done with Excel DNA?

Comment: Powerpivot sounds like the perfect tool for what you need.  It's free.

Comment: Need something that doesn't attempt to show many pivot rows of data.  If I have 2 million rows of data, I want to be able to have a cell showing the sum or row count and not see the rows of data.